# How to insert the multiline commands output into a same cell in csv file while redirecting the ouptut

Tags: bash, shell, csv

[enter link description here][1]I am creating a csv file, which contains the server health checks report from the bash script.
here am struggling with redirecting multiline command ouptut into a single cell, for me its getting all in  different cells.

eg:
command is: `echo "$server,$RootFreeSpace,$Uptime,$OSVersion,$TotalProcess,$ServerLoad,$Memory,$Disk,$CPU" >> $FILE`

$Disk has multiline output,for me its getting redirected in different cells I want to get all the output of any particular command to be redirected into single cell,

Searched a lot but did not found much information.

Comment: What do you want to do with the new lines characters, just replace them by spaces or smth? In that case you can pipe echo's output through sed to replace \n by " "

Answer (score 1):

In csv you have to quote linebreaks and other special symbols by writing the whole cell in quotation marks: `"cell value"`. A `"` inside the cell value has to be escaped by doubling: `""`.

The following function quotes each each of its arguments as a csv cell and prints all these cells as one csv row.

```
asCsvRow() {
  printf %s\\0 "$@" |
  sed -z 's/"/""/g;s/.*/"&"/' |
  tr \\0 , | head -c-1
  echo
}
```

In your case you would use it like

```
asCsvRow "$server" "$RootFreeSpace" "$Uptime" "$OSVersion" "$TotalProcess" "$ServerLoad" "$Memory" "$Disk" "$CPU" >> "$FILE"
```

Comment: thought csv is just a text file with some char as delimiter

Comment: The csv "standard" is defined in [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: @Socowi thanks for the solution, I executed the script by add the code you shared, am seeing the complete output in linux, but when I copy the file on windows server and open in spreadsheet its showing just first 7 charcter in first column and all other fields are blank

Comment: @SreekanthKondaiah I cannot help you with the Windows/spreadsheet problem unless you post the problematic csv file and specify what software you use to open it. Please post these informations by *editing* your own question.